# Cannot display View (Programmatically)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning how to make an app with just a code in Swift. I have encountered this problem:

This is action of a button.

```
@objc func answerAction() {
        
        let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AccountViewController") as! AccountViewController
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
```

If I press it, it shows this error:

**Thread 1: "Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle </Users/mas/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A3BEC6D0-3AA6-4193-A755-1181DD580576/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C80D5D36-EBD8-44D4-AF14-B64E2E7E5587/AppForTest.app> (loaded)"**

As I understand, the problem is that I have deleted [Main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuVXM.png) and app cannot reach it. So how I should declare in a answerAction **story** constant?

Comment: Where do you hold your AccountViewController UI layer if you removed storyboard and from the screenshot you attached, it looks like you dont have xib file. If you want to implement it programmatically, you dont need storyboard.

Comment: If you are not using storyboards remove the `let story = ...` and replace `let controller = ...` with `let controller = AccountViewController()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@objc func answerAction() {
    
    let controller = AccountViewController()
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)  
}
```